# Error in Java program missing packages

Tags: java

I tried to run the java program but missing packages.

```
import org.activiti.engine.*;
public class RawDriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration().setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE).setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:my-own-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000").setJobExecutorActivate(true).buildProcessEngine();

        System.out.println("processEngine = " + processEngine);


    }
}
```

How can i import external packages and run the program?

Comment: Have you added corresponding jar files to classpath?

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Comment: Running program In Linux command prompt

Comment: I don't know much about linux, but this link may help you http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

The external packages need to be in your classpath. This can be set as an environment variable or on the command line. You need to have the libraries associated with what you need which are usually shipped as jar files. More about the classpaths here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: On the Linux command line the short version would be:

`export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jarfile.jar`

Answer (score 0):

if the external packages are in another project, you can import that project, then in the project you are writing, choose Java build path -> project, add the project you just import. Then go to your java file and import the packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using esclipse , if you have a jar file then you can add the jar file to you classpath using the project --->Properties-->java build path

add the jar in the project libraries , you will be able to access external packages like this .

if you using command line option or unix , set the class path using the command line option set CLASSPATH option.

Hope this helps

Abhi